# R cut function tails less than other subsets

Tags: r, cut

I'm trying to split a data set into deciles.  I gave all the rows an id # (1:nrow(dataset)), then I use the cut() function to assign each row to a decile.

```
> df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:1000, cutter1 = NA)
> head(df1)
  id cutter1
1  1      NA
2  2      NA
3  3      NA
4  4      NA
5  5      NA
6  6      NA
> df1$cutter1 <- cut(df1$id,10, labels = F)
> table(df1$cutter1)

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Above is what I expect, however when I increase the # of rows to 100000 I see some weird behavior in the 1 and 10 deciles.

```
> df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:100000, cutter1 = NA)
> head(df1)
  id cutter1
1  1      NA
2  2      NA
3  3      NA
4  4      NA
5  5      NA
6  6      NA
> df1$cutter1 <- cut(df1$id,10, labels = F)
> table(df1$cutter1)

    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
 9920 10020 10020 10020 10020 10020 10020 10020 10020  9920
```

I played with the `include.lowest` and `right` parameters but they didn't fix anything.  Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I am assuming this is just a test dataset...? Deciling based on a column of "NA"s doesn't have much meaning.. Could you please post a more realistic dataset?

Comment: It's deciling on id which is populated from 1:nrow(dataset). The NA's just allocate space.

Comment: From `?cut`: "When `breaks` is specified as a single number, the range of the data is divided into `breaks` pieces of equal length, *and then the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range* to ensure that the extreme values both fall within the break intervals." (italics are mine).

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure the format of the output works for you, but this could be an alternative solution:

```
decile <- with(df1, cut(id, breaks=quantile(df1$id, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.1)), include.lowest=TRUE))
res = table(decile)
names(res) <-as.character(seq(1:10))
```

This works fine even in the case of :
`df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:100000, cutter1 = NA)`